# Get variables names from a data frame in a vector

Tags: r, vector, names

I can obtain the names of my variables of a data frame with the command "`names (df)`". It gives say:

```
#[1] "V1"  "V2"  "V3"
```

But I would like to obtain a vector, something like this:

```
c("V1", "V2", "V3")
```

Is this possible in R?

Thanks in advance for your response

Richard

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. `names(df)` is the vector `c("V1", "V2", "V3")`. If you want to print `c("V1", "V2", "V3")`, you can do `dput(names(df))`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's exactly that I need !

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and you can just make a new vector with the names like this:

```
x <- names(df)
```

..and the names will be stored in vector x